# Checking if a view exists before loading a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I would like to see if a *view exists before loading a fragment*. In my method that loads the fragment i have below :

```
 public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Begin Fragment transaction.
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();// Replace the layout holder with the required Fragment object.


    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.outbound_dashboard_hourly_queued, fragment);
    // Commit the Fragment replace action.
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

What i want is to check if `R.id.outbound_dashboard_hourly_queued` exists before loading

How do i proceed ?

Comment: do you mean if same fragment exits or any other fragment ?

Comment: `if(findViewById(R.id.outbound_dashboard_hourly_queued)!=null)` then do your work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do `findViewById(R.id.outbound_dashboard_hourly_queued)` and then load the fragment if the view is not Null keep a if check.

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Begin Fragment transaction.
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();// Replace the layout holder with the required Fragment object.
    View yourView= findViewById(R.id.outbound_dashboard_hourly_queued);
    if(yourView!=null){
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.outbound_dashboard_hourly_queued, fragment);
    // Commit the Fragment replace action.
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**Check is Fragmnet added or not**

```
 if (getCurrentFragment() instanceof YourFragment)
```

**Add Framgnet**

```
replaceFragment(new HomeFragment(), "YourFragment");
```

**Methods**

```
    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag)
    {
        Fragment currentFragment = getCurrentFragment();
        if (currentFragment != null)
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(currentFragment).commit();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_main, fragment, tag).commit();
    }

    public Fragment getCurrentFragment()
    {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        return manager.findFragmentById(R.id.container_main);
    }

    private void popBackStack()
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        int total = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use findFragmentByTag(String tag) method provided by FragmentManager to check if the fragment already exists or not.

`Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);`

For this to work, you need to commit your fragment with that TAG using -

`fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.outbound_dashboard_hourly_queued, fragment, TAG);`

Answer (score 0):

please follow the count checking before replace if the count == 0 add else replace your code must be like

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Begin Fragment transaction.
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();// Replace the layout holder with the required Fragment object.

    if(fragmentManager.getFragments().size() == 0){
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.outbound_dashboard_hourly_queued, fragment).commit();
    }else {
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.outbound_dashboard_hourly_queued, fragment).commit();
    }
    // Commit the Fragment replace action.

}
```

please try with this and let me know.